# Switching visualization using drop down - spotfire

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

I have a multiple visualization (side by side chart) in one page. could someone help me to switch from side by side to vertical bar using iron python in spotfire 7.8. Creating a drop down list in text area where can select vertical or side by side bar using the same data. any help is very much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

i tried this code the visualization is working the problem is the x-axis and y-axis values was change. what should be the chartype of side by side?

```
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data import *
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals import *

#if chart == "Bar":
if Document.Properties["charType"] == "Bar":
   viz.TypeId = VisualTypeIdentifiers.BarChart

   viz.AutoConfigure()

#elif chart == "SidebySide":
elif Document.Properties["charType"] == "SidebySide":

   viz.TypeId = VisualTypeIdentifiers.PieChart

   viz.AutoConfigure()
```